# KOMA-Script: After redifinition of \maketitle, page number cannot be removed any longer

Tags: header-footer, titles, koma-script, page-numbering

I tried to modify `\maketitle`: different `\vspace`s, date at the very bottom.

Unfortunately, as soon as I add the code to change `\maketitle`, the line `\renewcommand{\titlepagestyle}{empty}` has no effect anymore.

How can I disable the page number on the first page and move the date to the location of the page number?

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=14,a4paper,parskip=true,titlepage=true]{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
  % taken and shortened from /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
  \global\@topnum=\z@
  \setparsizes{\z@}{\z@}{\z@\@plus 1fil}\par@updaterelative
  \null
  \vskip 22em%
  \begin{center}%
    \ifx\@subject\@empty \else
      {\usekomafont{subject}{\@subject \par}}%
      \vskip 1.5em
    \fi
    {\usekomafont{title}{\Huge \@title \par}}%
    \vskip .5em
    {\ifx\@subtitle\@empty\else\usekomafont{subtitle}\@subtitle\par\fi}%
    \vskip 1em
    \null\vfill
    {\usekomafont{date}{\@date \par}}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 0em
  \clearpage
}%
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\titlepagestyle}{empty}


\subject{Opinion 12}

\title{My Opinion}
\date{1 August 2017}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{here gets}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why messing around with internals? I suggest to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage

Comment: Thanks for your input. I consider to make out of this a template with pandoc that calls \maketitle by default. If there is a less complicated way to change \maketitle without loosing koma features, I'm eager to hear about it. (I'll read the source suggested by @Johannes_B).
@Schweinebacke, how can I use the page style in my redefinition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\titlepagestyle` is used only on in-page titles made with `titlepage=false` and KOMA-Script's original `\maketitle`. You are using `titlepage=true`, so KOMA-Script itself wouldn't use `\titlepagestyle` even without your redefinition of `\maketitle`. You are defining a title page only, no in-page title. It is recommended (and mentioned in the KOMA-Script manual) to use `titlepage` environment for title pages. The original `\maketitle` definition in KOMA-Script also uses `titlepage` for title pages.

You can add `\begin{titlepage}` at the very beginning of your redefinition and replace the `\clearpage` at the end by `\end{titlepage}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=14,parskip=true]{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
  % taken and shortened from /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
  \begin{titlepage}
  \global\@topnum=\z@
  \setparsizes{\z@}{\z@}{\z@\@plus 1fil}\par@updaterelative
  \null
  \vskip 22em%
  \begin{center}%
    \ifx\@subject\@empty \else
      {\usekomafont{subject}{\@subject \par}}%
      \vskip 1.5em
    \fi
    {\usekomafont{title}{\Huge \@title \par}}%
    \vskip .5em
    {\ifx\@subtitle\@empty\else\usekomafont{subtitle}\@subtitle\par\fi}%
    \vskip 1em
    \null\vfill
    {\usekomafont{date}{\@date \par}}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 0em
  \end{titlepage}
}%
\makeatother

\subject{Opinion 12}

\title{My Opinion}
\date{1 August 2017}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{here gets}

\end{document}
```

[image: title page with <code>titlepage</code>]

BTW: With your redefinition not only `\titlepagestyle` is unused. Option `titlepage` also cannot change the behaviour of `\maketitle` any longer. The redefinition is very extrem. So it does not make sense to set the option or to redefine `\titlepagestyle`. I have removed them from the example.